# Memory-efficient two-way-mapping in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, two-way

I need to create a two-way mapping from ints to an object. I can't use the [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) because my objects are modified after being placed in the mapping (they are being modified in ways that do not affect the mapping).

The simple solution is two use a `vector` and an `unordered_map`:

```
vector<MyClass> _vector;
unordered_map<MyClass, size_t> _map;
```

However, this maintains two copies of each `MyClass`, and I don't want that.

I can keep `MyClass *` pointers in one of the containers, and use the storage of the other, but I'm afraid either `vector` or `unordered_map` can move the instances around (when reallocating the vector, or resizing the hash table).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How would you handle erasing from the vector, or would you not allow that?

Comment: I'd say that's what `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` is for.

Comment: The boost::bimap documentation says that you can modify things that don't affect the mapping, in some setups of bimap  , perhaps fewvisit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And can't you just store your objects in one vector and save the mapped indexes in another?

```
std::vector<MyClass> vC;
std::vector<unsigned int> vM;
```

Then `vC[vM[i]]` is the mapped class of the `vC[i]` object.

Though if you give more details about what you are trying to do (is the map reflexive? All classes have a mapped class or just some? How often you need to modify your objects?) we could help a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in your main container, and [`std::weak_ptr<MyClass>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in the referencing one.

Unfortunately you didn't give enough context or requirements, to give you a concise example. Anyway, you should also have some synchronization management, that removes entries from the referencing container, as soon these are erased from the main container, though `std::weak_ptr` makes this easier to implement.

Not only this is more memory efficient, it also relieves you from keeping otherwise unrelated copies of `MyClass` in sync.